# YII2: Filter in a Tab apply to all Tabs

Tags: php, yii2

I've just managed (thanks to another answer) to show different results of the same model in two different Tabs. But now when I add a Filter in one of the two tabs, the filter apply to the other tab as well. 
For example with that code:

```
<?=
Tabs::widget([
'items' => [
[
    'label' => 'New Books',
    'content' =>  GridView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                    'columns' => [
                        [
                            'label' => 'Book Name',
                            'attribute' => 'book_name',
                            'value' => 'book_name',
                        ],

                    ],
                ]),
],
[
    'label' => 'Old Books',
    'content' => GridView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProviderException,
                    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                    'columns' => [
                        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                        //'id',
                        [
                            'label' => 'Book Color',
                            'attribute' => 'book_color',
                            'value' => 'book_color',
                        ],
                        [
                            'label' => 'Book Name',
                            'attribute' => 'book_name',
                            'value' => 'book_name',
                        ],
                         ],
                ]),
      ],
],
]);
?>
```

For example if I search for a book name in a Tab, the same filter apply to both Tabs that is not what I want.

That's my Action in the controller

```
    public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new BookSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProviderException = $searchModel->searchException(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'dataProviderException' => $dataProviderException,
    ]);
}
```

And this is my modelsearch (all of this are simplified version)

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\book\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\modules\book\models\Book;
use yii\db\Expression;

class BookSearch extends Book
{
public $location;
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'pages', 'author_id'], 'integer'],
        [['name', 'color', 'release_date'], 'safe'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * @param array $params
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Book::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'pages' => $this->pages,
        'author_id' => $this->author_id, 
        'name' => $this->name, 
        'color' => $this->color,
        'release_date' => $this->release_date,
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}

public function searchException($params)
{
    $query = Book::find();

    $dataProviderException = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProviderException;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'pages' => $this->pages,
        'author_id' => $this->author_id, 
        'name' => $this->name, 
        'color' => $this->color,
        'release_date' => $this->release_date,
    ]);

    return $dataProviderException;
}
```

}

Edit: sorry I have changed somethings to make it more readable but I made it worse. Inside BookSearch I created two functions "search" and "searchexception" that in index.php are assigned to "dataProvider" of each tab. 
Now I need that a filter applied to one of the two tab will be not applied to the other as well

Comment: Please add your SearchModel and the ontroller action.

Comment: How do you create $searchOldModel and $dataProviderOld ? .. please could you explain ..